# Materialize css icons doesn't show up in Safari browser

Tags: html, css, safari, materialize

I noticed that `materialized CSS` icons does not show up in `Safari (v5.1.7 (7534.57.2)`. Well searched a lot on this topic but there haven't been any documentation on browser compatibility where safari has been listed. Could anyone let me know if this is a bug which needs to be fixed or are there any alternatives to get this work in Safari.

**Other browsers**

[image: Other browsers]

**Safari Browser**

[image: Safari Browser]

> PS:Other functionalities of `materializecss` works well except icons

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced the exact same issue. The following approach helped me:

- I was facing problems with the font-icons provided by materialize css. There seems to be some problem with the font-icons in case if you are self-hosting it. I will update my answer with the exact bug number. So to fix it I downloaded and used the font-icons provided by Google and followed the steps mentioned over [here](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/).
- Be sure to append the following to your CSS:

  ```
  .material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;

    /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

    /* Support for Firefox. */
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

    /* Support for IE. */
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  }
  ```
- Another thing to make sure is to see to it that you are using all the font formats provided by google: WOFF2, WOFF, Truetype, EOT and even SVGs if possible to ensure cross browser compatibility.

In case if you are not self hosting the font-icons, just try including the above mentioned CSS code. I haven't tried this with CDN but it did work for me for self-hosted font-icons. So let us all know how things work out, so that in case if it doesn't, we can try some alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

suddenly you have the Lockdown mode on. Go to safari menu > settings > websites > Lockdown Mode, and turn it off on the websites you have there.