# materialize css tabs not working on safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, materialize

Good evening,

I'm working on a page using materialize css, everything's working fine on other browser (chrome, firefox, IE). But somehow, there's something wrong with my materialize tabs. The fonts not even showed up on the page. I'm using Safari 5.1.7.

This is how the tab looks like, the font didn't even showed up.

[image]

Would appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **[`Refer this question and answer here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044052/materialize-css-icons-doesnt-show-up-in-safari-browser)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao still not working, i'm gonna update the question with the screenshot